# Manipulate the MS-Word Navigation Pane via VBA-Macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there any way to manipulate the content of MS-Word's Navigation Pane via VBA Macros. I found that I can get the navigation pane object via `Application.CommandBars("Navigation")` and manipulate its width or hide/unhide it, but what I am looking for is manipulation of the document outline ("Headings"), specifically folding/unfoloding specific items.

My specific use-case is to adjust which headings are folded and which are unfolded according to my general document structure, where the first 5 chapters contain general information (with many subchapters) that I hardly ever need to access. So I want to write a macro that folds those chapters while it opens other subsections which I frequently use.

Tried so far:

```
Sub CustomizeNavPane()
    Dim navpane As Object
    Set navpane = Application.CommandBars("Navigation")
    navpane.Width = navpane.Width - 20
End Sub
```

Expected:
Getting a NavigationPane object with specific methods for the Navigation Pane as opposed to a generic CammandBar object with generic methods.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible, see [Navigation Pane in Word 2016: VBA code to force collapsed view of headings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55885338/navigation-pane-in-word-2016-vba-code-to-force-collapsed-view-of-headings)

Comment: I already feared the same. Thanks for posting the link.